# Unable to return correct response from Query Handler in XUnit Test

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, xunit.net, mediatr

I have the following controller:

```
[HttpGet("")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> FetchCurrentCompany()
{
    var data = await _mediator.Send(new CompanyQuery());

    return Ok(data);
}
```

Which send a query

```
public class CompanyQuery : QueryBase<string>
{
   public CompanyQuery() { }
}
```

Which has a handler

```
internal class CompanyQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<CompanyQuery, string>
    {
        public CompanyQueryHandler()
        {
            
        }

        public async Task<string> Handle(CompanyQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Hello Company API");
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to write a test that'll call the API and in return pass back "Hello Company API"

When I debug the test, it doesn't hit

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Hello Company API");
```

Instead, it just says the test past, and the result doesn't actually have "Hello Company API"

Below is the test

```
private readonly Mock<IMediator> _mockMediatR;

public ApiControllerTest()
{
    _mockMediatR = new();
}

[Theory]
public async Task Get_Company_Details_Should_Return_Company_Information()
{
    // Arrange
    var controller = new CompanyController(_mockMediatR.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await controller.FetchCurrentCompany();

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```

Can someone shed some light into what I'm doing wrong, so that I can return the expected message from the handler?

Comment: Do you need to test the controller method or can you test the handler?